# abstract methods in abstract classes using CDI "Inject" throws weld exception

Tags: xml, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

I am having a relatively plain class hierarchy with a parent class that gets a utility class injected with CDI. Reading the Java EE documentation, I understand that have to annotate the class a @Decorator and the delegate i.e. the class being injected as a @Delegate like shown below:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Decorator
public abstract class BetGroup {

    public abstract List<OBCouponDTO> buildDTO();

    @Inject
    @Delegate
    OBInstanceFactory obInstanceFactory;

//..

}
```

When I start the server (Wildfly 10) it complains about the included signature for an abstract method i.e buildDTO().

Subclasses just provide trival processing in their implementation of this method. Anyway it outputs that the abstract method should be declared by a given decorated type.

Copy/pasting the exception message (i.e. "WELD-000090: A decorator...") into google opens the online Weld documentation chapter 10 which explains how cdi injection works in abstract classes, but not what one can do when the abstract class contains methods declared as abstract (=the challenge I am facing).

Anyone having a clue about what I am doing wrong here?

```
15:11:45,177 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."obrmsexposer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."obrmsexposer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000090: A decorator has an abstract method that is not declared by any decorated type
  Method: [EnhancedAnnotatedMethodImpl] public abstract dk.danskespil.domain.BetGroup.buildDTO()
    at dk.danskespil.domain.BetGroup.buildDTO(BetGroup.java:0)
  StackTrace:
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Decorators.checkAbstractMethods(Decorators.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DecoratorInjectionTarget.checkAbstractMethods(DecoratorInjectionTarget.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DecoratorInjectionTarget.<init>(DecoratorInjectionTarget.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.<init>(ManagedBean.java:100)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.DecoratorImpl.<init>(DecoratorImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.DecoratorImpl.of(DecoratorImpl.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createDecorator(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:274)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:221)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Other relevant information:

Testing on windows 7
Wildfly 10.0.0 started from Idea 14.0.4
jdk1.8.0_40

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    
        dk.danskespil.domain.BetGroup

Comment: it's not the abstract method that throws an Exception, rather an implementation of said method

Comment: Following @Stultuske comment, I'd advise you to take a careful reading at the [Decorators' documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#decorators).